# ruby 1.9.2 does not support pg gem? cant heroku rake db:migrate (

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1.0
please help, cause i very need it to work for studying. It's my university project(

i have installed this gems

```
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
```

but when i use heroku rake db:migrate is tells me to instal postgreadapter. But i have it.

I did all that i read about this problem, also did

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

in rubymine it writes gem "pg" is not available in SDK 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'

same with thin and heroku gems

Comment: can you update your post to include the output of your db:migrate? the pg gem should work find with rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.2

Comment: it does work fine - I can assure you of that.

Comment: but it's well worth installing PG locally to run the same DB as heroku - it can save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not installed those gems in rubymine (locally). run "bundle install" or if you need to do something specific in rubymine to install gems.